# display a radio button based on a variable in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, html

I thought I had a solid plan to do this but somehow or the other it is not working...
But what I did, I have a variable on a web page some where (this is an asp.net MVC application).  Based on what this variable is, I will change the style of one of two div's two visible and then remove the style attribute (I have both of those two divs with a style element set to "display:none").  Now the first one works but the second one does not?  I keep getting a javascript error that tells me that an object is required (I would give you the exact error but my web server isn't working for some reason).

```
  Activate/Deactivate Patient 
  <div id="deactivateNO" style="display:none"><%=Html.RadioButton("deactivate", "N", false)%>Deactivate</div>
  <div id="deactivateYES" style="display:none"><%=Html.RadioButton("deactivate", "A", false)%>Activate</div>
```

Those are the div's that I have described with the radio buttons inside.  What follows are the javascript functions I call to make one of those divs appear or disapear...

```
function ShowMessage() 
{
    var timer = setTimeout("Show()", 1200000);
    //debugger;
    var active = "<%= Active %>";
    if (active == "A")
    HideActivate();   
    if (active == "N")
    HideDeactivate();     
}

function HideActivate()
{
    //debugger;
    var obj = document.getElementById("deactivateNO");
    obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
    obj.removeAttribute('style');
}
function HideDeactivate() {
    //debugger;
    var obj = document.getElementById("deactivateYes");
    obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
    obj.removeAttribute('style');
}
```

The first function calls either of the final two functions.  The first function seems to work well.  The second function seems to be giving me trouble... When I have my debugger going, it always bugs out on the obj.style.visibility = 'visible';  When I look at the obj object it is always null?  Which tells me that it can't find the deactivateYes Id?  I have looked at the source and it appears as though it is there.  I will double check, but I am pretty sure it is.

Comment: While it should be unimportant, the casing of your IDs are mismatched on the `HideDeactivate` method, i.e. `Yes` vs `YES`.

Comment: also why are updating the style on an element then removing the styling completly?

Comment: that is a good point.  I wrote this initially like a week ago (just now getting around to testing it), and I forget my precise logic, but I am sure there is a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is deactivateYes and deactivateYES the same...

this is why it will fail to find the element, the ids dont match

have to really careful about case ;)

Comment: I am such a fool.  You know what I did, I did a search on the ID and I found the id in the searchByID() call, so I just assumed that the cases matched... I should have known that the parameter was a string and it was up to me to make sure the cases matched.  I also should have noticed that I had my search set to not match case...

Comment: it's a easy mistake to make, one I think everyone has and will keep making, until the end of time...